# How to share one SQLite database b/w two android phones connected using Wifi Direct

Tags: android-intent

I have 2 Android phones connected using Wifi Direct say A and B. I am using SQLiteOpenHelper to write and read from SQlite database on Phone-A. How can I access the database created on Phone-A from Phone-B.

I have full rights on both Phones.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Either copy the data from *Phone-A* to *Phone-B* or code some server daemon on *Phone-A* and the corresponding client on *Phon-B*; beware that SqlLite was not designed for concurrent access.

Comment: Thanks Basile Starynkevitch